# SQL how to rearrange column in order (From big to small value)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table [PRODUCT] for product and margin. I need to make sure MG1>MG2>MG3>...>MG9
How do I rearrange this column in easier manner?
[image]

Tried using If else and case and end up with a very long code.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show the results that you want.  You cannot rearrange the columns because they are not in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot and re-aggregate.  Here is one method:

```
select id, sku,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then mg end) as mg1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then mg end) as mg1,
       . . . 
       max(case when seqnum = 9 then mg end) as mg9
from (select i.*, row_number() over (order by mg desc) as seqnum
      from (select id, sku, mg1 as mg from t union all
            select id, sku, mg2 as mg from t union all
            . . .
            select id, sku, mg9 as mg from t 
           ) i
      where mg is not null
     ) i;
```

If you are using SQL Server -- or another database that supports lateral joins -- then the best method is:

```
select t.id, t.sku, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then mg end) as mg1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then mg end) as mg2,
             . . . 
             max(case when seqnum = 9 then mg end) as mg9
      from (select mg, row_number() over (order by mg desc) as seqnum
            from (values (t.mg1), (t.mg2), . . ., (t.mg9)
                 ) v(mg)
            where mg is not null
           ) v
      ) v;
```

There is a big performance advantage in doing the `group by` in the subquery versus in the outer query.

Comment: Thanks both. Works like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with ordered as (
    select ID, SKU,
        mg, row_number() over (partition by ID order by mg desc) as rn
from T cross apply (
    select * from (values (mg1), (mg2)) as dummy(mg)) as up
)
select ID, SKU,
    min(case when rn = 1 then mg end) as mg1,
    min(case when rn = 2 then mg end) as mg2
from ordered
group by ID, SKU
```